# How to specify a multi-instrument 2SLS

Tags: r, regression

I'm looking for a compact way to specify a multi-instrument 2SLS in R.  Imagine that there are four treatment categories (A, B, C, and D).  There are two waves of measurement, Y_1 and Y_2.

A regression of Y_1 on treatment yields estimates of the immediate effects of B, C, and D (relative to A).  Similarly, a regression of Y_2 on treatment, yields the over-time effects of B, C, and D.

The ratio of these estimates is a way to characterize the proportion of the treatment effect measured at time 1 that remains at time 2.

```
N <- 100000

df <- data.frame(
  Y_2 = rbinom(n = N, size = 1, prob = .5),
  Y_1 = rbinom(N, size = 1, prob = .5),
  Z = sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), N, replace = TRUE)
)

# Fitting both with lm, then taking the ratio
fit_1 <- lm(Y_1 ~ Z, data=df)
fit_2 <- lm(Y_2 ~ Z, data=df)

coef(fit_2)[2:4] / coef(fit_1)[2:4]
```

Alternatively, you could use 2SLS, but right now, the only way I can figure this out is to do 2sls separately for B vs A, C vs A, and D vs A.  My question is, how to specify the 2sls so that it's all done together?

```
# install.packages("AER")
library(AER)

# Fitting with 2SLS, but having to subset!

fit_B <- ivreg(Y_2 ~ Y_1 | Z == "B", data = subset(df, Z %in% c("A", "B")))
fit_C <- ivreg(Y_2 ~ Y_1 | Z == "C", data = subset(df, Z %in% c("A", "C")))
fit_D <- ivreg(Y_2 ~ Y_1 | Z == "D", data = subset(df, Z %in% c("A", "D")))

# Same answer (at least asymptotically??)
coef(fit_2)[2:4] / coef(fit_1)[2:4]
c(coef(fit_B)[2], coef(fit_C)[2], coef(fit_D)[2])
```

I've tried some things like

```
ivreg(Y_2 ~ Y_1:Z - 1 | Z, data=df)
```

but it doesn't work.  Any thoughts?

Comment: In what sense doesn't it work?

Comment: it doesn't return the same coefficients as `coef(fit_2)[2:4] / coef(fit_1)[2:4]` ... it's estimating SOMETHING, but not any quantities that I think I'm interested in...